# Tool that shows Python unit test coverage module-wise, analyzes static code quality and finds common poor practice

Tags: python, code-analysis

Is there any tool built specifically for python code quality and test coverage?

What i expect from that tool:

- To show unit test coverage module wise.
- To analyze static code quality and find common poor practice.

Comment: If you want to mention Sonarqube, just say what is wrong with it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no one tool that does everything. But the best tools for your requirements in my opinion are:

1. [coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy)
2. [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/)